# How to read and write a sequence of items where preciding items may refer to postceding items?

Tags: c++, io

I have a number of items in a tree structure. I can read and write them one by one along the tree iteration. However, there is reference pointer in the class Item, like below

```
class Item
{
    Item* m_refItem;
    ...
};
```

If the referenced item is before the referencing item in the tree, we can use the the referenced item's index in read and write, like below

```
void read()
{
    Index index;
    in >> index;
    m_refItem = getItem(index);
}
```

However, if the referenced item is after the referencing item, when reading the referencing item, the referenced item is not constructed and the getItem(index) method give a wrong result. How to do the reading and writing in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in two phases:

1. Read all the nodes and store indexes.
2. Replace all indexes with pointers.

code:

```
class Item {
    union {
        Item* m_refItem;
        int _index; }
    void read_phase_one(stream in) {
        in >> _index; }
    void read_phase_two(vector vect) {
        m_refItem = vect[index]; }
```